# Add binding to json using JavaScriptSerializer with list asp.net c#

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, binding

I use to build my json return string by hand using vbscript and would add a binding, and then in javascript i could say something simple like

```
data.response[0].key
```

which would look like this in json

```
{"response":[{"key":"value"},{"key":"value"}] }
```

I just starting working with jquery ajax to asp.net in c# and i found the only way to make valid json in c# is to use the JavaScriptSerializer.  This is fine, except im not sure how to get that type of binding when serializing my list.  I only have one item in my json for testing

```
d=[{"h":"hi"}] //This is what shows in fiddler
```

i want it too look similar to the above

```
d={"response":[{"h":"hi"}] }
```

Im not sure how to create this type of json response object using c#, though i am sure it is possible.  Here is the code for my test serialization.

```
private static string Serialize(object obj)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serializer.Serialize(obj);
}

public static string SomeMethod()
{
    List<Samp> samp = new List<Samp>()
    {
        new Samp{h = "hi"}
    };
    return Serialize(samp);
}
```

/

```
public class Samp
{
    public string h = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return Serialize( new { response = samp });`

Comment: This formats exactly how i am use to, thank you!!
with that being said, there must be some other issue.  If i say
alert(data.response);  I get 'undefined', when i look at fiddler i see d={"response":[{"h":"someHTML"},{"h":"someHTML"}]}  im not sure how it could possibly not be defined

Comment: Will you link me to your fiddler so I can take a look?

Comment: data = JSON.parse("{\"response\":[{\"h\":\"h1\"}] }") will parse the json string into an object that has a response property.  In other words: data = "{\"response\":[{\"h\":\"h1\"}] }" makes data a string where alert(data.anything) throws an error.  But this will work correctly for the first method alert(data.response[0].h)

Comment: i think my json isnt returning at all.  I can alert from the success callback but data.response is undefined.  If i place the code you added above it runs fine, but the actual data returned to the success function seems to be empty.

Comment: thanks for all the help and your awesome answer to my org question! i posted a new question to hopefully get this return situation under control.